# Setting up OpenGL camera

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics, 3d, opentk

I'm having trouble setting up my camera in 3D space.

Here's my code:

```
private void SetupViewPort()
    {
        GL.Viewport(0, 0, glControl1.Width, glControl1.Height);
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.LoadIdentity();
        GL.Ortho(0, 1000,0,1000, 0, 1);

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.LoadIdentity();

        Vector3d eyePos = new Vector3d(0, 0, 1);
        Vector3d point = new Vector3d(500, 500, 0.01);
        Vector3d up = new Vector3d(0, 0 , 1);
        Matrix4d mat = Matrix4d.LookAt(eyePos, point, up);
        //mat.Invert();
        GL.LoadMatrix(ref mat);

    }
```

I'm expecting to see shapes that I've drawn onto the 2D plane. But I get a blank screen every time.

Here's the code where my shapes are drawn:

```
private void glControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!loaded)
            return;
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
        GL.DepthMask(true);
        GL.ClearDepth(1.0);
        GL.Color3(Color.Yellow);
        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Triangles);

        GL.Vertex2(0, 0);
        GL.Vertex2(0, 600);
        GL.Vertex2(600, 600);
        GL.Vertex2(100, 100);
        GL.Vertex2(50, 70);
        GL.Vertex2(200, 100);

        GL.End();

        glControl1.SwapBuffers();
    }
```

Comment: FYI: Everything you have in `SetupViewPort` belongs into the drawing code. OpenGL's state-machine-ness allows you to get away with setting the viewport and projection at other places, but in the long run doing so just causes headaches.

Comment: Everything? I would have thought from about line 5 downwards belongs in the drawing code.

Comment: Everything! Especially setting the viewport. Setting the viewport in the resize handler is what hits the hardest the moment you want to use framebuffer objects. As a general rule *always* do a full viewport and projection setup right before you need those being set in the drawing code. There's no cost associated with it whatsoever, because the relevant GPU commands have to be sent anyway for each and every drawing batch.

Comment: Okay thanks datenwolf. Any idea why I'm getting a black screen though?

Comment: Hard to tell from your code. A few things come to mind. If you had CCW back face culling enabled the order in which you specify your triangles vertices would cull the triangles. Then of course `loaded` may be false. Your near clip plane is at z_near=0, your vertices' z coordinate is at 0, too, which may clip them as well (fix for that would be to ortho z in [-1, 1] )

Comment: I just tested each of those items and none appears to make any difference. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

An orthonormal projection matrix and a lookAt view matrix don't play well together. Since you are drawing 2D just leave the lookAt matrix out and use the identity matrix.

Comment: This program is a test because I intend to use the idea in a much bigger 3D world. I really need to figure this out in 3 dimensions - sorry!

Comment: Okay, then use a perspective matrix as a projection matrix.

There should be a C# port of GLU with the function gluPerspective which does the trick.

Comment: I need to use an orthographical view for the problem I'm solving. I've already done the whole thing with a perspective matrix and it wasn't adequate.